# Can I have an application scope variable in Perl?

Tags: perl, variables, scope, cgi

I'm somewhat new to Perl/CGI, and I'm coming from a Java/JSP background.

I'm writing a small prototype and need to load some "heavy" data (~200MB) into a data structure.

Now, I'd obviously like to avoid loading the data with every request. So far I managed to use a "static" variable (one enclosed in a {} block), but this seems to work for a few requests. After some inactivity time, the next request will have to load the data again.

From my JSP experience, this would seem to be a sort of session variable that remains available until the session expires.

How can I set a "global" or "application" variable? Not sure if these terms apply to CGI...
Is it possible to have a variable shared by all sessions of an application?

Btw, I'm just using "use CGI qw(:standard)" at the moment.

Comment: The data is dynamic for each particular user? Or is it dynamic for a particular period of time, but for all users during that time span?

Comment: Since this just popped up again, let me mention, the proliferation of Perl frameworks as well as better Apache tie-ins (mod_perl etc) have pretty much killed any reason to use CGI, at least directly.

Answer (score 6):

CGI scripts are executed and then terminate after each request.  Your 200 MB variable will be loaded each time.

You should put this data into a database or other structured format that will allow you to load data only as you need it.

Look into something like [MLDBM](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MLDBM/lib/MLDBM.pm), [DBD::SQLite](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-SQLite/lib/DBD/SQLite.pm), or [DBM::Deep](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBM-Deep/lib/DBM/Deep.pod)

See [Coping with Scoping](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Namespaces.html) for info on variable scope in Perl.

[Ovid's CGI Course](http://jdporter.perlmonk.org/cgi_course/) is also a good resource for learning to write CGI scripts in Perl.

Comment: Not bound by CGI per se, I'm running an Isapi handler from IIS 7 (gasp!), which handles .pl extensions.

This is for a fast internal prototype, so a DB solution would be quite more time intensive than I'd like...

thanks!

Comment: That's why the suggested modules are lightweight DBIs.  You need some way to share information between processes, and these are the fastest way to get there.

Answer (score 5):

CGI programs are run in a separate process for each request.  This is part of the [CGI protocol](http://hoohoo.ncsa.illinois.edu/cgi/interface.html).

So this isn't possible so long as you're bound to CGI.  Are you sure that you're bound to CGI?

If you're running Apache, and that Apache has mod_perl either compiled in or available as a dynamically loaded module, it's possible to run the perl scripts in process and re-use the data; there's even a compatibility mode wherein you can write your CGI scripts as normal (using "use CGI") and they get automatically mod-perl-ized so that stuff inside BEGIN blocks is only run once.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Storable module and its freeze/thaw methods to freeze your object structure and temporarily store it? [CPAN > Storable](http://http:/search.cpan.org/~ams/Storable-2.20/Storable.pm)

Storable would allow you to write and retrieve your structure to and from anything that can be considered a database, including Berkley, or even flat files. While 200 MB is a large chunk to store, you might regroup the data into smaller hashes that easily go back together.

And it is super fast.

Answer (score 1):

Try [CGI::Session](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI::Session) module.

*Note however that like Daniel Martin and daotoad wrote peristency is **outside** scope of CGI; you would have to emply some kind of extra storage to save state.*

Answer (score 0):

I would consider looking into [CGI::Fast](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI.pm/CGI/Fast.pm) if I were you.  CGI::Fast makes it easy to write a persistent CGI program.  Another good option, depending on what your data structure is like, is to use [Cache::Memcached](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Cache-Memcached/lib/Cache/Memcached.pm) (or its faster cousin [Cache::Memcached::XS](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Cache-Memcached-XS/lib/Cache/Memcached/XS.pm)) to move the data structure out of your program but still leave it in memory.